# What is the difference between using Active Record exists? versus find_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my model, I check if a `Sudoku` record exists in the database first before I either fetch it's `solution` or create it.

```
if Sudoku.exists?(puzzle: puzzle)
  return Sudoku.find_by(puzzle: puzzle).solution
else
  **solve it and save it into the db**
end
```

What is the difference from doing this:

```
if Sudoku.find_by(puzzle: puzzle)
  return Sudoku.find_by(puzzle: puzzle).solution
else
  **solve it and save it into the db**
end
```

**Logs for `exists?`**

```
Sudoku Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "sudokus" WHERE "sudokus"."puzzle" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["puzzle", "390820700801500069020160403002096058935000602060752030703941000200037590019000347"]]
  Sudoku Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sudokus".* FROM "sudokus" WHERE "sudokus"."puzzle" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["puzzle", "390820700801500069020160403002096058935000602060752030703941000200037590019000347"]]
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

**Logs for `find_by`**

```
 Sudoku Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sudokus".* FROM "sudokus" WHERE "sudokus"."puzzle" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["puzzle", "390820700801500069020160403002096058935000602060752030703941000200037590019000347"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sudokus".* FROM "sudokus" WHERE "sudokus"."puzzle" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["puzzle", "390820700801500069020160403002096058935000602060752030703941000200037590019000347"]]
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

At first, I thought by doing two `find_by` it would hit the database twice, but then I see the CACHE. Does that mean Rails remember the previous query in the first `find_by` and is only hitting it once?

Why would I use `exists?` over `find_by` ?

**Edit:**

From advice, I'm using this now:

```
if sudoku = Sudoku.find_by(puzzle: puzzle)
  return sudoku.solution
else
  **solve it and save it into the db**
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails wraps each controller action with a simple query cache. The `CACHE` in the logs does indicates that the query was served from the cache. If you were to run that code in the console you wouldn't get that caching (unless you explicitly set that up).

The difference query wise is that none of the fields of the object are fetched from the database. Aside from the network impact, depending on the query and the indices present, your database may be able to use a covering index (in a nutshell the index can be used to answer the query completely instead of the db using the index to find the data for the row)

On top of that rails doesn't construct an active record object from the result, you just get back true/false.

So `exists?` is faster. However it's pointless if you then call `find_by` straight after. You might as well call `find_by` once only.

Comment: Exactly this! Adding on to "You might as well call find_by once only", I'd go ahead and assign the `find_by` query to a variable, that way you already have it and don't need to even hit a cache. `if sudoku = Sudoku.find_by(puzzle: puzzle)`